# How to ask Espresso to run UI tests before doing network Operations?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am testing happy path of my application that contains several activities. Just for sake of simplicity assume that I have three activities.

1. There is a button in first activity that I can click it (via Espresso)
2. Seconds activity creates Booking object based on what data first activity passed in and send a request to server. If server returns success then third activity displays.
3. Third activity displays to let user now that Booking was successful.

My problem is in second step:

```
{
...
// first activity
onView(withId(R.id.btnBooking)).perform(click());

// second activity
secondActivity_checkInitialViewsState();

// third activity
thirdActivity_checkInitialViewsState();

}

private void secondActivity_checkInitialViewsState()
{
    // viewsMustBeVisible 
    onView(withId(R.id.title)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed())); // <= Error
    onView(withId(R.id.sonarView)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));        
    onView(withId(R.id.cancelBooking)).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()));        
    onView(withId(R.id.listView)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

    // viewsMustBeEnabled 
    onView(withId(R.id.tvNoServiceFound)).check(matches(not(isCompletelyDisplayed())));        
    onView(withId(R.id.tvNextSearch)).check(matches(not(isCompletelyDisplayed())));
}
```

I'm getting following error in my log after running the test:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
>   hierarchy found matching: with id: com.my.package:id/title If the
>   target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use
>   Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following
>   AdapterViews:com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.n{291fbd0f G.ED..C.
>   ......I. 0,0-0,0}

The reason behind that is (I think at least) Espresso framework waits for UI events in the current message queue to process and default AsyncTasks to complete before it moves on to the next test operation and not using any time synchonization. Therefore once my backend sends `sucess` the app displays third screen while Espresso tries to run `secondActivity_checkInitialViewsState()` and that error displays.

So my question is, is there any way that I ask Espresso to run this method first (even in different thread).

Answer (score 0):

Espresso is not really meant to test across Activities like that, it's meant to test a single Activity in isolation, otherwise you'll end up with flaky tests.  That is why Google created `ActivityTestRule` for us to use.  Your "happy path" test should really be three different Espresso test classes:

The first test should test that pressing the button launches the second Activity, using espresso-intents:

`intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), SecondActivity.class)));`

The second test should test your step 2.  You can mock the intent data sent to the Activity.  Similarly, you should check that the third Activity is launched.

The last test should test your step 3.

Comment: Thanks for your point of view @trevor. I actually started by the way you are suggesting but it has a lot of difficulties including redundant codes such as that `intended` for every activities, dependency injection for every activity, etc. So I decided to simulate what user does with the app. In this way I create and object exactly the way user does and pass this object among activities and examine the status of Booking Objects in every screen. This help us to find bugs easily although the way you are suggesting has its own advantages.